# How to apply coordinate transformations

Tags: geometry, functions, transformation

Lets say I want to rotate a parabola by $\pi/4$ degrees counterclockwise.
Wikipedia tells me a counterclockwise transformation would mean: 
$$ 
x'=x\cos t-y\sin t \\ 
y'=x\sin t+y\cos t  
$$
however when I substitute these new expressions into $y=x^2$, the graph appears rotated clockwise
$$
(x\sin(\pi/4)+y\cos(\pi/4)) = (x\cos(\pi/4)-y\sin(\pi/4))^2  
$$
(try it in wolframalpha)

why is it working in reverse, how should these transformations work?

---

to be more specific regarding my problem
I need to do a coordinate transformation to model a distortion in an image but I do not understand what the expression means.

if I wanted to apply the transformation $x' =$ sign$(x)x^2$ where $x'$ corresponds to the "image plane", what would I get?

my intuition tells me that if I had a point at $(0.5,0.5)$, it would be pulled into $(0.25,0.25)$ but this website tells me the opposite

http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/imagewarp/

I am aware of $r_u=r_d+kr_d$ 3 transformations, I want to use $x^2$

but if I substitute $x^2$ and $y^2$ into the equation of a circle, I see that the circle looks inflated
$$
[\mbox{sign}(x)x^2]^2+[\mbox{sign}(y)y^2]^2=1
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your substitution is not rotating $y=x^2$ -- on the contrary you're starting with $y'=x'^2$ and rewriting that to express the same points in the $xy$ coordinate system.

With the transformation you're quoting, the $xy$ coordinate axes are rotated an angle of $t$ *clockwise* from the $x'y'$ coordinate axes.

Thus when you take a parabola with its axis along the $y'$ axis and "turn the paper" such that the $y$ axis points due north, the $y'$ axis will now point to the *northeast*.

If you want to rotate an image *counterclockwise*, then you need its *original* coordinates in the $xy$ coordinate system, and find a new description for it in the $x'y'$ system. That means that you need to invert the transformation to express $x$ and $y$ as functions of $x'$ and $y'$ -- or just negate the angle you rotate through.

---

Expressed in other words, there's a difference between rotating a *point* and rotating an *equation*. If your transformation is $T$, and $\phi(v)$ is an equation whose solution set you want to rotate, then you are after the set
$$ \{ T(v) \mid \phi(v) \} $$
In order to get an *equation* for the rotated set, you can change the variable to $u=T(v)$, and then you get
$$ \{ u \mid \phi(T^{-1}(u)) \} $$
So you construct an equation for the transformed set by composing the existing equation with the *inverse* of the transformation.

Comment: oh, ooooooh. thank you very much.